# PhpOffice laravel | Шапка для документа

Tags: laravel, phpword

Использую плагин PhpOffice(PhpWord) для laravel. Необходимо сделать такую шапку для документа.
Думаю, можно из этого сделать:

```
$styleTable = array('borderSize' => 6, 'borderColor' => '999999');
$phpWord->addTableStyle('Colspan Rowspan', $styleTable);
$table = $section->addTable('Colspan Rowspan');

$row = $table->addRow();

$row->addCell(null, array('vMerge' => 'restart'))->addText('A');
$row->addCell(null)->addText('B');
$row->addCell()->addText('1');

$row = $table->addRow();
$row->addCell(null, array('vMerge' => 'continue'));
$row->addCell(null, array('vMerge' => 'continue', 'gridSpan' => 2));
$row->addCell()->addText('2');
$row = $table->addRow();
$row->addCell(null, array('vMerge' => 'continue'));
$row->addCell()->addText('C');
$row->addCell()->addText('D');
$row->addCell()->addText('3');
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализация с помощью таблицы.

```
        $section = $phpWord->addSection();

        $styleTable = array(
            'borderSize' => 6,
            'borderColor' => 'ffffff',
            'align' => 'right',
            'valign' => 'center'
        );
        $phpWord->addTableStyle('Colspan Rowspan', $styleTable);
        $table = $section->addTable('Colspan Rowspan');

        /***BEGIN шапка документа BEGIN***/
        $row = $table->addRow();
        $row->addCell()->addText('');
        $row->addCell()->addText('LOREM IPSUM', [], [
            'align' => 'center',
            'spaceBefore' => 0,
            'spaceAfter' => 0,
            'spacing' => 0
        ]);
        $row->addCell()->addText('');

        $row = $table->addRow();
        $row->addCell(null, array(
            'gridSpan' => 3,
            'vMerge' => 'restart'
        ))->addText('lorem ipsum', [], [
            'align' => 'center',
            'spaceBefore' => 0,
            'spaceAfter' => 0,
            'spacing' => 0
        ]);

        $row = $table->addRow();
        $row->addCell(null, array(
            'gridSpan' => 3,
            'vMerge' => 'restart'
        ))->addText('lorem ipsum', [], [
            'align' => 'left',
            'spaceBefore' => 0,
            'spaceAfter' => 0,
            'spacing' => 0
        ]);

        $row = $table->addRow();
        $row->addCell(null, array(
            'gridSpan' => 3,
            'vMerge' => 'restart'
        ))->addText('lorem ipsum', [], [
            'align' => 'right',
            'spaceBefore' => 0,
            'spaceAfter' => 0,
            'spacing' => 0
        ]);

        $row = $table->addRow();
        $row->addCell(null, array(
            'gridSpan' => 3,
            'vMerge' => 'restart'
        ))->addText('lorem ipsum', [], [
            'align' => 'left',
            'spaceBefore' => 0,
            'spaceAfter' => 0,
            'spacing' => 0
        ]);
        /***END шапка документа END***/
```

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.mirocow.com/doku.php?id=php:docx_doc
Тут достаточно подробно расписано как можно настроить блоки